# Vertically centering the text in a title

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'd like that the text of my title starts always at the same place (that it is vertically centered always at the same height; in the example provided below the first title is higher than the second because 'g' uses space below, whereas 'a' does not). I'd like the bottom part of the g's to be under the line drawn. Even if I move the line further, the text centering is always like that. Also if I place it with respect to (b) and below it. How can I change it?

```
\documentclass[17pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
\vskip1cm
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \node(a)[fill=black,rectangle,minimum width=.25cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=north west]at(current page.north west){};
\node(b)[anchor=west]at(a.west){\insertframetitle};
\draw[red, line width = 1mm, below left=1cm and 3cm of a](a.south west)--+(11.8,0);
  }
  \vskip-1cm 
}

\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Gggg}
}
\frame{\frametitle{Aaaa}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\strut` is the command you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[17pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \vskip1cm
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
        \node(a)[fill=black,rectangle,minimum width=.25cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=north west]at(current page.north west){};
        \node(b)[anchor=west]at(a.west){\strut\insertframetitle};
        \draw[red, line width = 1mm, below left=1cm and 3cm of a](a.south west)--+(11.8,0);
    }
    \vskip-1cm 
}

\begin{document}
    \frame{\frametitle{Gggg}
    }
    \frame{\frametitle{Aaaa}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @John Great! Maybe you'll have to shift the red line a bit higher to get the text centred.